# why output of rndr instruction is mixed with bootloader's entropy to form linux kaslr on arm64

Tags: linux-kernel, arm64

It is code snippet from Linux kernel (arch/arm64/kernel/kaslr.c) how kaslr seeed is obtained:

```
u64 __init kaslr_early_init(u64 dt_phys)
{
  ...

    /*
     * Retrieve (and wipe) the seed from the FDT
     */
    seed = get_kaslr_seed(fdt);


    /*
     * Mix in any entropy obtainable architecturally if enabled
     * and supported.
     */
     if (arch_get_random_seed_long_early(&raw))
            seed ^= raw;
      ...
}
```

Does someone can explain why seed is xor'ed with output of arch random instruction (RNDR instruction that appears in ARMV8.5 Random extensions).  If we already have bootloader's entropy then why need additionally get arch random?

Comment: Because why not?

Comment: @Siguza Does mixing bootloader's entropy with arch random makes seed stronger?

Comment: Yes, I'd assume so.  Early boot is one of the worst cases for availability of entropy, since there hasn't been time yet to accumulate entropy from the low bits of the clock on interrupts.  (And embedded systems often don't have much random timing other than the network, where packet timing is potentially observable by an attacker.)  So the bootloader's entropy is likely quite low.